# Query Request on graphiql

Tags: javascript, graphiql

Since I already thank you for the space, I'm with following problem with graphql, I followed the commands by a public api site, AniList https://anilist.gitbook.io/anilist-apiv2-docs/overview/graphql/getting-started, I can get a lot of information, but what I wanted I'm not getting, I would like to catch the characters of an anime, if anyone can help me would be very grateful, I'm very layman on the subject, I'll leave the code here

```js
var query = `
{Media (id: 1, type: ANIME) { 
    id
    title {
      romaji
      english
      native
    }
  episodes
  type
  averageScore
  seasonYear
  episodes
  duration
  characters {
    nodes {
      image {
        large
        medium
      }
    }
  }
  coverImage {
    extraLarge
  }
  }
}
`;


var url = 'https://graphql.anilist.co',
    options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            query: query,
        })
    };

fetch(url, options).then(handleResponse)
                   .then(handleData)
                   .catch(handleError);

function handleResponse(response) {
    return response.json().then(function (json) {
        return response.ok ? json : Promise.reject(json);
    });
}

function handleData(data) {
    //console.log(data.data.Media.title.userPreferred);
    //document.getElementById("anime").innerHTML = data.data.Media.title.userPreferred;
    
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = data.data.Media.title.english;
    document.getElementById("type").innerHTML = data.data.Media.type;
    document.getElementById("episodes").innerHTML = data.data.Media.episodes;
    document.getElementById("averageScore").innerHTML = data.data.Media.averageScore;
    document.getElementById("duration").innerHTML = data.data.Media.duration;
    document.getElementById("episodeList").innerHTML = data.data.Media.episodes;
    document.getElementById("dateanime").innerHTML = data.data.Media.seasonYear;
    document.getElementById("anime_image").setAttribute("src", data.data.Media.coverImage.extraLarge );
    document.getElementById("anime_person").setAttribute("src", data.data.Media.characters.image.large );

     
}

function handleError(error) {
    alert('Error, check console');
    console.error(error);
}
```

```css
#main, .autofill {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    margin: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: -5px;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #0000007d;
    line-height: 2.9rem
}
```

```html
<div class="autofill">
    <strong>name: </strong><span id="title"></span>
    <br />
    <strong>type: </strong> <span id="type"></span><br />
    <strong>N. episodes: </strong> <span id="episodes"></span><br />
    <strong>Score: </strong> <span id="averageScore"></span><br />
    <strong>duration: </strong> <span id="duration"></span> <br />
    <strong>Status: </strong> <span id="episodeList"> </span> <br />
    <strong>In: </strong> <span id="dateanime"></span><br />
    <span>
       <img src="" id="anime_image"> <br />
        <img src="" id="anime_person"> <br />
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
characters = data.data.Media.characters.nodes
```

This will return an array which you can iterate over to get each character:

```
characters[0].image.large
```